# What version of JUnit is the Play Framework using?

Tags: junit, playframework-2.0, sbt

How do I find out the exact JUnit version of my Play! 2 installation?

From a quick web search I see that in Play 1 I could consult the file `/framework/dependencies.yml`, right?

I am fairly new to the Play Framework and I do not know yet how sbt works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this is to write:

```
show test:dependency-classpath
```

to sbt console. Find it somewhere in the output.